# Requiring initialization file in all directories in PHP

Tags: php, directory, init

So I have an initialization file named "init.php" in a directory called "core". Inside this init file, I have "required" all other necessary component files within a directory called "classes" and hence init.php has a few lines of "require_once". Every time I create a file in the root directory (for example creating "index.php"), I have to include this file i.e. "include core/init.php". It all went well until I tried including this init file within a file created in another directory. For example, in a directory called "levels/index.php". I keep getting an "include" error everytime I include this init file inside a directory other than the root directory.

Here's how my init.php file looks like:

```
//load all class files automatically
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
});

//include functions
require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';
require_once 'functions/functions.php;
```

Now my index.php file located at the root directory looks like this:

```
include 'core/init.php';
```

No errors were displayed, however another PHP file for example (source.php) inside a directory called "levels" triggered an errors saying

> Warning: require_once(functions/sanitize.php): failed to open stream

Here's how my source.php file looks like:

```
include '../../core/init.php';
```

I hope there's a solution to this cause I'll be having troubles maintaining all my files located only at the root directory. Sometimes I would wanna include the initialization file in a file inside other directories. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should use absolute path. First define a path, only exmaple: `define('ROOT_PATH', 'localshot/')` and then include file like `require_once ROOT_PATH . 'core/init.php'`